# TikZ: difference between \node and \coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

What is the  difference between `\node` and `\coordinate` in `TikZ`? Exchanging them does no visual effect in my (to be honest: still simple) pictures.

When to use what?

Comment: `\coordinate` has a bad name.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Well, perhaps it's interesting to look at the pgfmanual :

1. `\coordinate` is a shortcut for `\path ... coordinate[⟨options⟩](⟨name⟩)at(⟨coordinate⟩) ...;`
2. and it's the same that `node[shape=coordinate][]⟨options ⟩](⟨name ⟩)at(⟨coordinate ⟩){},` where the `at part` might be missing.

   > Since nodes are often the only path operation on paths, there are two
   >   special commands for creating paths containing only a node: `\node`
   >   Inside `{tikzpicture}` this is an abbreviation for `\path node`.
   >   `\coordinate` Inside `{tikzpicture}` this is an abbreviation for
   >   `\path coordinate`.
3. pgf and TikZ define three shapes, by default:

   - rectangle,
   - circle, and
   - coordinate.

   > The coordinate shape is handled in a special way by TikZ. When a node
   >   x whose shape is coordinate is used as a coordinate (x), this has the
   >   same effect as if you had said (x.center). None of the special “line
   >   shortening rules” apply in this case. This can be useful ...
4. finally

   > The exact behaviour of shapes differs, shapes defined for more special
   >   purposes (like a, say, transistor shape) will have even more custom
   >   behaviors. However, there are some options that apply to most shapes.

It's why some default values like `inner sep` are different.

Comment: Thanks. Was really hard to decide the correct answer. But I took this one because it was the most detailed one. But I upvoted all others, too.

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain why the label position is different and how to get EXACT positioning with `\coordinate` command, in the following: `\coordinate [distance=0cm,label={O}] (O) at (0,0);` versus `\node (0,0) {O};`. Counterintuitively the latter is doing the "right" thing. (the `distance` option was an attempt to get the label on top of the stated coordinates). Thanks! (If you think I should ask a new question, I will)

Answer (score 86):

`\node` requires a caption:

```
\node (name) at (coordinate) {caption};
```

`\coordinate` does not use a caption:

```
\coordinate (name) at (coordinate);
```

`\node` can also have a shape and dimension, `\coordinate` is just a point

Comment: So, can I always use `\node` to be fully flexible (future changes maybe require new captions or shapes)?

Comment: Also, a `coordinate` is basically just a `node` with the node shape `coordinate`, so saying `\node [coordinate] (<name>) at (<coordinate>) {};` is equivalent to `\coordinate (<name>) at (<coordinate>);`

Comment: Note that coordinates don't occupy space. So if you set a node (without visible content) somewhere, the tikz graphic will actually occupy that space (although invisibly, but it's still there, which u can test, e.g., by surrounding it by a fbox). This does not happen with a coordinate. Sometimes u need coordinates to do some computations, in particular if u compute the position of other nodes.

Comment: @Jake If I do `\node[coordinate] (name) at (x1,y1) {caption};` I don't see any caption at that (x1,y1) point. Why is that? How do I make tikz to draw my text there?

Comment: @tush A coordinate does have no text (“caption”). Use a node shape that does.

Comment: I think it is very misleading to call the node contents a 'caption'. If anything should be called a 'caption' here (and I think it would be better not), wouldn't it be a label, which a coordinate can also have?

Answer (score 43):

`node` introduces an `inner sep` and hence does not produce a geometrical point in true sense. `coordinate` or `\node [coordinate]`  on the other hand, does not have `inner sep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\verb|\node|  introduces an \verb|inner sep|:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (cone) at (0,0);
    \node (none) at (4,0) {};
      \draw[->] (cone) -- (none);
    \draw[draw,red,->] (none) -- (0:5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb|\node[coordinate]| or \verb|\coordinate|  does not introduce an \verb|inner sep|:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (cone) at (0,0);
    \node[coordinate] (none) at (4,0) {};     %% or \coordinate (none) at (4,0);
      \draw[->] (cone) -- (none);
    \draw[draw,red,->] (none) -- (0:5);
\end{tikzpicture}

If you use \verb|\node|, you may be forced to use \verb|none.center| to get rid of the gap noticed between the two lines:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (cone) at (0,0);
    \node (none) at (4,0) {};
      \draw[->] (cone) -- (none.center);
    \draw[draw,red,->] (none.center) -- (0:5);
\end{tikzpicture}

Hence, when you need a geometric point, use \verb|\node[coordinate]| or \verb|\coordinate|.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bottom line: When you need a point *use `coordinate`*.

Comment: Very good answer: thanks for making **so clear** the *equivalences* and *differences* between these two concepts. Brilliant!

Answer (score 23):

```
\coordinate[⟨options⟩](⟨name⟩)at(⟨coordinate⟩) ...;
```

This has the same effect as

```
\node[shape=coordinate][⟨options ⟩](⟨name ⟩)at(⟨coordinate ⟩){}
```

This can be read in the tikz documentation. It is obvious, that `coordinate` has no content. It's mainly used for defining coordinates for referring them with names.

`\coordinate` btw is a  abbreviation for `\path coordinate`.

Answer (score 8):

I'm learning TikZ these days. I didn't really understand the answers above until I finished the following exercise.

1. With `\coordinate`:

   ```
   \usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning,backgrounds,fit,calc}
   \usetikzlibrary{through}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
       \def\A{\textcolor{input}{$A$}}
       \def\B{\textcolor{input}{$B$}}
       \def\C{$C$}
       \def\D{$D$}
       \def\E{$E$}
       \colorlet{input}{blue!60!black}
       \colorlet{output}{red!60!black}
       \coordinate [label=left:\A] (A) at (0,0) ;
       \coordinate [label=right:\B] (B) at (0.8,0.2);
       \draw [color=input] (A) -- (B);
       \node [draw, name path=D,label=left:\D] (D) at (A) [circle through=(B)] {};
       \node [draw, name path=E,label=right:\E] (E) at (B) [circle through=(A)] {};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

   I got this,

   [image]
2. With `\node`:

   ```
   \usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning,backgrounds,fit,calc}
   \usetikzlibrary{through}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
       \def\A{\textcolor{input}{$A$}}
       \def\B{\textcolor{input}{$B$}}
       \def\C{$C$}
       \def\D{$D$}
       \def\E{$E$}
       \colorlet{input}{blue!60!black}
       \colorlet{output}{red!60!black}
       \node [label=left:\A] (A) at (0,0) {};
       \node [label=right:\B] (B) at (0.8,0.2){};
       \draw [color=input] (A) -- (B);
       \node [draw, name path=D,label=left:\D] (D) at (A) [circle through=(B)] {};
       \node [draw, name path=E,label=right:\E] (E) at (B) [circle through=(A)] {};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

   I got this,

   [image]

The difference is shown in intersection parts between the straight line AB and circles, which can help you to understand "`\node` can also have a shape and dimension, `\coordinate` is just a point".

Answer (score 0):

By default, a node has the following shapes: rectangle, circle, coordinate (see "17.2 Nodes and Their Shapes" and "17.2.2 Predefined Shapes" of the pgfmanual). Like Jake said a coordinate is basically just a node with the node shape coordinate. A coordinate has no way of taking a caption/node content because it is a point. Normally, the default shape for a node is a rectangle. In case "2. With node", if the code is changed to `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, every node/.style={draw}]`, a small square shows up in nodes A and B

[image]

which serves as a textbox to accommodate a caption as shown below.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning,backgrounds,fit,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, every node/.style={draw}]
    \def\A{\textcolor{input}{$A$}}
    \def\B{\textcolor{input}{$B$}}
    \def\C{$C$}
    \def\D{$D$}
    \def\E{$E$}
    \colorlet{input}{blue!60!black}
    \colorlet{output}{red!60!black}
    \node [label=left:\A, shape=circle] (A) at (0,0) {$Node\_A$};
    \node [label=right:\B] (B) at (0.8,0.2){$Node\_B$};
    %\node [label=right:\B, shape=rectangle] (B) at (0.8,0.2){$Node\_B$};
    \draw [color=input] (A) -- (B);
    \node [draw, name path=D,label=left:\D] (D) at (A) [circle through=(B)] {};
    \node [draw, name path=E,label=right:\E] (E) at (B) [circle through=(A)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]