# TikZ doesn't fill when node coordinates are used

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone please explain me why the following code doesn't result in a fill?

And why, sometimes, I get such "very thin lines" artifact (that's visibile in my picture)?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (1,0) {B};
\node (C) at (1,1) {C};
\fill[red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91310/19156), `nodes` have a shape and are not just *pure coordinate*.
Your example works if you replace the `fill` line by real node coordinates:

```
\fill[red] (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- cycle;
```

[image: result]