# Tikzpicture: Fill refuses to work with integer node names

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

I want to create a 3D-grid of named nodes using nested for loops and then fill some polygon based on the names. For some reason tikzpicture doesn't fill the polygon, although it draws the path alright.

I assume it has something to do with the node names.
Here is a minimal 2D-example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
  \foreach \j in {0,...,3} {
     \node at (\i, \j) (\i\j) {};
}}

\draw (00) -- (02) -- (12);
\fill (00) -- (02) -- (12);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output is the grid, with two lines but no fill.

Comment: See if [TikZ doesn't fill when node coordinates are used](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93867) solves your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: How to upvote Torbjorns comment?

Comment: @PeterJansson how to upvote comments :)

Comment: When you place your mouse cursor over a comment, an arrow should appear on the left side (unless there's a reputation limit, but I don't know if that's the case). Comment votes doesn't give any rep. But anyways, when a new question is a duplicate of an old one, we usually close the new question. That doesn't mean it's a bad question, it's just to keep things 'tidy'.

Comment: doesn't really matter I guess, but arrows don't appear for me.

Comment: @LeeviL: Are you using the mobile version of the site, maybe?

Comment: @jake no but I just found out that I did't have enough reputation (for a table of privileges see http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) with your comment I got the extra 1 rep I needed to vote up the comment =D