# names and nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

The underlying square in the following code ends up green, and not blue as I was expecting.

Are there some rules to be aware of ?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (v1) at (0,3) {};
\node (v2) at (0,-1) {};
\node (v3) at (-3,3) {};
\node (v4) at (-3,-1) {};
\fill[color=gray!20]
(-3,-1) -- (-3,3) -- (0,3) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
\fill[color=green!20]
(-3,-1) -- (-3,3) -- (0,3) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
\fill[color=blue!20]
(v4) -- (v3) -- (v1) -- (v2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93867/tikz-doesnt-fill-when-node-coordinates-are-used

Comment: If the node texts are empty, then use `\coordinate` instead of `\node`.

Comment: oh my.... so there *are* let and *types* :))) thank you !