# Circuitikz: connection of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, circuitikz

I'm using the `circuitikz` library to draw some circuits. To connect two nodes with a square angle, there is the possibility to use `|-`, as in the MWE below for the connection of (a) with (b). However, sometimes I don't like the way `circuitikz` connects the nodes (e.g. it sometimes draws line overlapping with other lines in large circuits), so in some cases I'd like to specify the coordinates where the square angles are inserted (e.g. sometimes I'd like to have two right angles as in MWE 2) or I want to insert a circle at a particular node and so on.

In the MWE, node (a) is connected with nodes (b), (c), (d) and (e).

- The connection with (b) is fine.
- For the connection with (c), I've inserted a circle, and the line
  after the circle doesn't start immediately at the circle but with
  some horizontal space inbetween.
- Same problem with node (d), but
  without the circle.
- Finally, I wanted to connect (a) with (e) by
  going further up (to (0,5)) and then from there to the right and down
  to (e). However, this isn't working properly either.

Any ideas how I can solve at least some of these problems?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw

(0,0) node (a){a}
(1,1) node (b) {b}
(2,2) node (c) {c}
(3,3) node (d) {d}
(3,4) node (e) {e}

(0,2) node (crossa) {}
(0,3) node (crossa2) {}
(0,5) node (crossa3) {}

(a) |- (b)
(a) to[short, -*] (crossa)
(crossa) -- (c)
(a) -- (crossa2) |- (d)
(a) -- (crossa3) |- (e)

;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very likely the problem lies in the use of nodes rather than coordinates (nodes have an `inner sep`>0). You might want to have a look to [TikZ: difference between \node and \coordinate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91310/13304)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thanks, it really works to change the connecting nodes to coordinates. Thanks a lot again! If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.