# Differences between paths drawn between nodes and coordinates in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

Referencing this very helpful [posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91310/tikz-difference-between-node-and-coordinate) and the Tikz manual, which states:

> Whenever TikZ encounters a whole node name as a “coordinate,” it tries to “be smart” about the anchor that it should choose for this node. Depending on what happens next, TikZ will choose an anchor that lies on the border of the node on a line to the next coordinate or control point.

I can see the difference in the way the following two paths are drawn:

[image: Paths between nodes vs. coordinates]

The second path is the preferred one.  My question is if there is a better way to integrate this into fewer commands.  I cannot seem to get a "point" drawn using the `shape=coordinate` inside `node[]`, and instead am drawing the actual points using filldraw.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,patterns,shapes.geometric,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,auto]
[bend angle=45]

\node[name=f,shape=ellipse,draw, thick, minimum width=50, minimum height=75] at (0,0) {};
\node[name=g,shape=ellipse,draw, thick, minimum width=50, minimum height=75] at (2,0) {};

\coordinate(f1) at ($(f.center) + (0,1)$);
\coordinate(g1) at ($(g.center) + (0,1)$);

\node at ($(f.center) + (0,-1)$) (f3) {};
\node at ($(g.center) + (0,-1)$) (g3) {};

\filldraw   
        (f1) circle (1pt)
        (f3) circle (1pt)
        (g1) circle (1pt)
        (g3) circle (1pt);  

\draw[->, >=stealth,bend left] (f1) to (g1);
\draw[->, >=stealth,bend left] (f3) to (g3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you daw the nodes you made you will understand that in one case you connect points in the other one you connect "boxes" aka nodes :

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,patterns,shapes.geometric,calc,positioning}

\tikzset{small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.25}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,auto]
[bend angle=45]

\node[name=f,shape=ellipse,draw, thick, minimum width=50, minimum height=75] at (0,0) {};
\node[name=g,shape=ellipse,draw, thick, minimum width=50, minimum height=75] at (2,0) {};

\coordinate(f1) at ($(f.center) + (0,1)$);
\coordinate(g1) at ($(g.center) + (0,1)$);

\node[small dot] at ($(f.center) + (0,-1)$) (f3) {};
\node[small dot,outer sep=3pt] at ($(g.center) + (0,-1)$) (g3) {};

\filldraw   
        (f1) circle (1pt)
        %(f3) circle (1pt)
        (g1) circle (1pt)
        %(g3) circle (1pt)
        ;  

\draw[->, >=stealth,bend left] (f1) to (g1);
\draw[->, >=stealth,bend left] (f3) to (g3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Man that was fast! I should've specified, I understand this already. What I would like to do is draw a point inside the node within the parameters of 'node' itself, if possible, rather than filldraw circles.

Comment: @AbbasJaffary See my edit.

Comment: `outer sep` is for this purpose

Comment: You mean '\coordinate[draw]'? I tried that and nothing shows up.

Comment: @AbbasJaffary No I don't mean that. Did I understand correctly what you want in my answer ? You can put the `outer sep=3pt` in the style, if you want to use it every time.