# How to get an arrow line from the center of the point (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw a Bezier curve and get points at 0.2,0.4 etc position. I want to draw a vector from one of the points. 
But the vector doesn't originated from the point. There is some gap between the point and the vector. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,black!50, step=0.5] (-1,-1) grid (6,6);
\draw[->,>=stealth',very thick] (-1,0)--(6,0);
\draw[->,>=stealth',very thick] (0,-1)--(0,6);
\draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (-5,1) .. (6,6)
\foreach \p/\l in {0.2/A,0.4/B,0.6/C,0.8/D} {node[pos=\p,label=$\l$,anchor=base](\l) {}};
\foreach \l in {A,B,C,D} {\draw[fill] (\l) circle (2pt);}
\draw[red, thick, ->, >=stealth'] (C) -- +(2,1) node[right] {$\vec F_C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would add a `coordinate` in the options of `node[pos=\p,label=$\l$,anchor=base](\l) {}`. See [TikZ: difference between \node and \coordinate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91310/13304)

Comment: Another possibility would be to use `(C.center)` instead of `(C)`.

Comment: @TomBombadil I already mentioned that in my answer

Comment: @krtek: That happens when I open many questions at once and don't realize somebody already answered in the meantime ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the anchor of the first arrow point to `C.center`. Is that what you mean? See [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) section *17.5 Positioning Nodes*

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,black!50, step=0.5] (-1,-1) grid (6,6);
\draw[->,>=stealth',very thick] (-1,0)--(6,0);
\draw[->,>=stealth',very thick] (0,-1)--(0,6);
\draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (-5,1) .. (6,6)
\foreach \p/\l in {0.2/A,0.4/B,0.6/C,0.8/D}     {node[pos=\p,label=$\l$,anchor=base](\l) {}};
\foreach \l in {A,B,C,D} {\draw[fill] (\l) circle (2pt);}
\draw[red, thick, ->, >=stealth'] (C.center) -- +(2,1) node[right] {$\vec F_C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]