# tkz-euclide, FillAngle

Tags: tkz-euclide

tkzFillAngle makes a small mistake when filling an angle and I don't know why.

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]    
        \node at (0:1) (point) {};
        \node at (30:1) (otherpoint) {};
        \node at (0:0) (O) {};
        \tkzFillAngle[fill=orange, size=0.3, opacity=0.4](point,O,otherpoint)
        % tkz code no ;
        \draw [dashed] (O.center)--(point);
        \draw (O.center)--(otherpoint);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{asdf}
\end{figure*}   
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get. Note how the filling doesn't go all the way to the corner of the angle. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I see an error of compilation: Missing chars `;`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Now I'm using Papeeria and I have this bit of error. Can you try here: https://www.papeeria.com. That is not, of course, the problem. In my opinion, there are some coordinate errors.

Comment: @Sebastiano When I compile the code in texpad (using the mactex distribution), I don't get any errors. Also I don't see where I could have misplaced a ;

Comment: @Fabian Don't worry. If you change the sequence point,O,otherpoint you have a complementary circular sector whose centre is not O.

Comment: Use \coordinate instead of node : `\coordinate  (O) at (0:0);` Nodes are extended objects, they come with `inner sep` and `outer sep`.

Comment: @marmot I was typing my solution while you were writing your comment, you could add another answer with nodes with `inner sep=0pt`.

Comment: It's not a very good idea to use a single line of tkz-euclide with tikz. In this case can use only Tikz or only tkz-euclide. With Euclide the main object is the point. It's a special node : a coordinate

Comment: @Sebastiano you're right there is a wrong ";" at the end of the  `\tkzFillAngle` instruction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `\coordinate` instead of `\node`.

See here: [TikZ: difference between \node and \coordinate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91310/tikz-difference-between-node-and-coordinate).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]    
        \coordinate (point) at (0:1);
        \coordinate (otherpoint) at (30:1);
        \coordinate (O) at (0:0);
        \tkzFillAngle[fill=orange, size=0.3, 
        opacity=0.4](point,O,otherpoint)% no ; here
        \draw [dashed] (O)--(point);
        \draw (O)--(otherpoint);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{asdf}
\end{figure*}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Fabian You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer! We always like to help users who post an MWE. Your question is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to define the points as just done @CarlaTex but it is also possible to define them with the macro `tkzDefPoint[< options >](x,y){name}`

The `tkzFillAngle` macro is not documented in the manual, but is quoted. 
The manual contains the `\tkzMarkAngle` macro which is used in the same way without being documented either.

The manual documents two macros that allow drawing angular sectors 
 `\tkzDrawSector` and `tkzFillSector` which allows to plot angular sectors. 
In order to understand the difference between these two macros, I drew the angular sector with each one without drawing the sides.

`\tkzDrawSector` draws the contour of the corner:

[image: draw-euclide]
`\tkzFillSector` colors it without drawing its contour:

[image: fill-euclide]

It is of course possible to draw and colour the angular sector at the same time.
In the example you gave, as the magnification is of factor 5, I put a radius 5 times smaller (2mm)

`tkz-euclide` Macros don't need semicolons.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]    
        \tkzDefPoint(0:1){point}
        \tkzDefPoint(30:1){otherpoint}
        \tkzDefPoint(0:0){O}    
%       \tkzFillAngle[fill=orange, size=0.3, opacity=0.4](point,O,otherpoint);
%       \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange, size=0.3, opacity=0.4](point,O,otherpoint);
%       \tkzFillSector[R with nodes,fill=orange, opacity=0.4](O,2mm)(point,otherpoint)
        \tkzDrawSector[R with nodes,fill=orange, opacity=0.4](O,2mm)(point,otherpoint)
        \draw [dashed] (O.center)--(point.center);
        \draw (O.center)--(otherpoint.center);
        \tkzDrawPoints(O,point,otherpoint)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{asdf}
\end{figure*}   
\end{document}
```

Output with `\tkzDrawSector`:

[image: draw-euclide-1]

Output with `\tkzFillSector`:

[image: fill-euclide-1]
Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: in the next version of tkz-euclide, I changed some options. No tkzMark,tkzFill, tkzDraw are specific macros. It's not possible to fill with draw or to draw with mark etc...

Comment: @AlainMatthes In my opinion, the most practical (user friendly) is to make as on tikz, a single macro corresponding to a single concept like `tkzSector` and whose options `draw`, `fill`, `mark`, allow to modify its use

Comment: Thanks for this nice overview! This cleared a lot of things up!

Answer (score 3):

With only `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]    
        % \node at (0:1) (point) {};
        % \node at (30:1) (otherpoint) {};
        % \node at (0:0) (O) {};
        \tkzDefPoint(0:1){point}
        \tkzDefPoint(30:1){otherpoint}
        \tkzDefPoint(0:0){O}
        \tkzFillAngle[fill=orange, size=0.3, opacity=0.4](point,O,otherpoint)
        % tkz code no ;
        \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](O,point)
        \tkzDrawSegment(O,otherpoint)
        % \draw [dashed] (O.center)--(point);
        % \draw (O.center)--(otherpoint);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{asdf}
\end{figure*}   
\end{document}
```

With only tikz it's possible to fill an angle. You have beautiful examples with the geometry lessons in the pgfmanual. And now you can use a `pic` with the recent version.

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer, that's the reason for the error reported by Sebastiano, then. I didn't look at the log because I answered using Overleaf.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I know I can fill an angle with just tikz, but I need tkz-euclide for some other parts, involving equilateral triangles etc.